# Intentional Sleep call for a user login in a web app - C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, authentication, sleep

I was wondering if the following will have an effect as I intend it. I'm writing a custom login page for my web application (using C# and ASP.NET) and I thought to add the following to ButtonLogIn_Click() event:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

My thoughts were to intentionally slow down the log-in process, not for too long for a human being to notice, but long enough to prevent possible "enumeration" or "brute force" attack by a machine.

In your opinion, will it have an effect as I intend it? Or will it just slow down the IIS?

**EDIT:** Thank you all for your contributions!

Comment: If you want to delay then only do it after a failed attempt to throttle the speed of repeated attempts. But thats probably not possible in a web application. Any old mainframe login screen will do it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will likely just make things worse as the attacker also ties up your threads. Unless you add other safeties, he can still make numerous concurrent login attempts.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the IP Address of the request and maintain a list of failed attempts. Based on IP address you can code so that you disallow a specific IP if too many attempts are being made.

You can also block request of an IP temporarily. See this link:
http://www.iis.net/download/dynamiciprestrictions

Answer (score 1):

I think this will not help at all since the requests (if done by a script) will wait in the Que and will make your IIS just suffer more, and you to kill the precesses after noticing the issue also harder.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem right to have to do this to be honest. There's usually structures/controls in place that would allow you to implement such basic security features. Is there nothing about? If you must code it yourself, then it'd be worth looking at maybe 'sleeping' the thread after numerous attempts (just like the windows OS login). You need to keep in mind the fact that with what you are suggesting - even a successful login will be slowed down. I think should you use thread.sleep after 7 or 8 attempts, for example, it's a lot more likely that you are sleeping a brute force attack's attempt at logging in.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.maxinvalidpasswordattempts.aspx

Possible solution. Like I thought, it did seem a bit strange that there wouldn't already be something out there.